# Can't set Depreciation Start Date with Assets API

Tags: assets, xero-api

I am trying to create a Fixed Asset in Xero using the API, not any SDK in particular.
Everything but the Depreciation Start Date seems to work properly.

The request body I send to Xero API:

```json
{
      assetName: 'Asset name',
      assetNumber: 'CA-46987', 
      serialNumber: '',
      purchasePrice: 432,
      purchaseDate: '2024-03-06T15:04:30.373',
      bookDepreciationSetting: {
        depreciationMethod: "StraightLine",
        averagingMethod: "FullMonth",
        effectiveLifeYears: 5,
        depreciationCalculationMethod: "Life"
      },
      bookDepreciationDetail: {
        depreciationStartDate: '2024-03-07'
      }
    };
```

The response I get back from Xero looks like this:

```json
{
...
  bookDepreciationSetting: {
    depreciableObjectId: '0965dc9e-3a5a-46f0-aac9-d7b7f0a466a5',
    depreciableObjectType: 'Asset',
    bookEffectiveDateOfChangeId: '98108fe1-9eaa-4145-b660-4f36ca2a5418',
    depreciationMethod: 'StraightLine',
    averagingMethod: 'FullMonth',
    effectiveLifeYears: 5,
    depreciationCalculationMethod: 'None'
  },
  bookDepreciationDetail: {
    depreciationStartDate: '2024-03-07T00:00:00',
    priorAccumDepreciationAmount: 0,
    currentAccumDepreciationAmount: 0,
    currentCapitalGain: 0,
    currentGainLoss: 0
  },
  taxDepreciationSettings: [],
  taxDepreciationDetails: [],
  canRollback: true,
  accountingBookValue: 432,
  taxValues: [],
  isDeleteEnabledForDate: true
}
```

As you can see, it responds with depreciationStartDate properly set to '2024-03-07T00:00:00'. Please note I only send the date component ('2024-03-07'), so this response suggests it's not a simple echo and that the date was processed.

Despite that, when I inspect the newly created Fixed Asset through Xero UI, the Depreciation Start Date is empty. All the other information are properly filled in. Is this a bug, or maybe I am missing some data?

I've tried playing with the date format:

- '2024-03-07'
- '2024-03-07T00:00:00'
- '2024-03-07T00:00:00.000'
- full ISO date

None of it worked.

Edit:
When I send the date in `"\/Date(1709769600)\/"` format, the response I get back suggests it was ignored:

```json
...
  bookDepreciationDetail: {
    priorAccumDepreciationAmount: 0,
    currentAccumDepreciationAmount: 0,
    currentCapitalGain: 0,
    currentGainLoss: 0
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find, because of its .NET framework, [Xero docs](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/requests-and-responses#:%7E:text=JSON%20responses%20and%20date%20formats) explicitly state the use of Unix epoch formatting for dates and timestamps when dealing with JSON.

So, for your request to work, you'll need to convert the date or `'2024-03-07'` to either one of the following:

Epoch timestamp (UTC): `"\/Date(1709769600)\/"`

Epoch timestamp in milliseconds: `"\/Date(1709769600000+0000)\/"`

Comment: This is not the case, unfortunately. 
Note that the purchase date transfers properly, and shows in the UI. 
Also, Xero official documentation (https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/assets/assets) states that the date has to be sent in the following format:
depreciationStartDate YYYY-MM-DD

The excerpt you mentioned is about the date format Xero responds with.

Comment: @styku what was the API return response if you input an epoch timestamp format? or the responses you have gotten from inputting other timestamp formats?

Comment: Edited the question to include response JSON. This format is not used when sending stuff to Xero, every POST that accepts a date requires a string format.